# Рекурсия и стек

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, стек

В общем единственная тема, которую я никак не могу понять - это рекурсия. Написал маленький код, но не понимаю как он работает до конца.

```
function power (base, exponent){
   if (exponent == 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return base * power(base, exponent -1);
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
```

Можете ли объяснить по шагам как тут всё устроено?

Comment: а что вы уже читали по этой теме?

Comment: а как вы себе сами объясняете что такое *рекурсия*?

Comment: Это вызов функции внутри другой функции, это я знаю.

Comment: А просто гуглили про рекурсию? В интернете чрезвычайно много информации по этому поводу. И даже с визуализацией её работы.

Comment: Ещё общий совет: пройдите отладчиком по своему коду. Вы это умеете?

Comment: что именно непонятно?

Comment: @Данил это вызов функции из самой себя, если быть точнее )

Answer (score 3):

Вызываем функцию с параметрами **(2,3)**, т.е. функция имеет данный вид:

```js
function power (2, 3){
   if (3 == 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return 2 * power(2, 3 - 1);
}
```

Далее функция(назовем ее внешняя) вызывает сама себя и создает новый уровень вложенности( назовем клон 1 ),  (PS внешняя не может завершиться пока не завершатся все внутренние(клоны))
далее клон 1 вызывает сам себя и создает новый уровень вложенности( назовем клон 2 ),
далее клон 2 вызывает сам себя и создает новый уровень вложенности( назовем клон 3 ),
далее на клоне 3 срабатывает условие **if**, значит **return 1** и клон 3 возвращает **единицу** клону 2.
На клоне 2 срабатывает условие **else** т.е. 2 * 1( единицу вернул клон 3) , и результат(двойка) возвращается  клону 1
На клоне 1 срабатывает условие **else** т.е. 2 * 2( двойку вернул клон 2 ), и результат(четверку) возвращает внешней функции
На внешней функции срабатывает условие **else** т.е. 2 * 4( четверку вернул клон 1 ), и возвращает результат(восьмерку ) в консоль.

Нарисовал схему работы данной функции:

[image: Пример работы рекурсии javascript]

Answer (score 2):

```
function power (base, exponent){
   //Посчитаем силу базы (хз что это, но надо так надо :)

   //Если экспонента точно равна нулю, то мы знаем ответ!
   if (exponent == 0) {
       return 1; //и он равен нулю
   }
   else { //Но если экспонента нулю не равна, то ответ мы не знаем

       //Попробуем уменьшить экспоненту на 1 и посчитать снова
       exponent = exponent - 1;

       //результатом работы функции будет число, умноженное на результат работы ЭТОЙ же функции, но с экспонентой, уменьшенной на 1
       return base * power(base, exponent);
   }

   //Если придет значение экспоненты меньше нуля, то все, браузеру хана :)
}
```

Comment: `power` - в данном случае - возведение в степень. Параметры обозначают соответственно какое число будет возводиться, и в какую степень.